# Can't use list from another file in Python

Tags: python

I have a script that imports a list from another file. The list contains an almost-dictionary, so I ran a loop through it to turn it into a dictionary, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Redefinition of unused productOrdersListPulled
```

What am I doing wrong?

My code is:

```
import ast
import re
from api import productOrdersListPulled

# This script removes some  characters from the messy dictionaries,
# Afterwards, they are a dictionary, recognizable by python

# regex to find unneeded data in the file
order_item = re.compile("<OrderProducts at 0x[\da-f]+, ({.*?})>", re.I)


def transformInDictionary(productOrdersListPulled):

    # opens up the file with the unstructured data, and use it as a iterator

        for line in productOrdersListPulled:
            productOrdersListWithLine = [ast.literal_eval(op) for op in re.findall(order_item, line)]
        return productOrdersListWithLine

transformInDictionary()
```

And the other file is:

```
import bigcommerce

# Script used to pull OrderProducts data from the Big Commerce API.

# login to bigcommerce api
api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(host='*******.mybigcommerce.com', basic_auth=('**********', '*************'))


# create lists
def createLists():

    productOrdersList = list()
    ordersList = list()
    productsList = list()
    return productOrdersList, ordersList, productsList


# update range if orders ids goes higher than this
# try,except, pass added so the for loop keeps looping even if IDs are not found
# remember to update range (higest so far: 615982)
def pullOrdersProductsData(productOrdersList):
    for x in range(614530, 614535):
        try:
            productOrdersList.append(api.Orders.get(id="{}".format(x)).products())
        except:
            pass
    return productOrdersList


# loop over the list and get the orders with the IDs
def pullOrders(ordersList):
    #  remember to update range (higest so far: 615982)
    for x in range(614534, 614535):
        try:
            ordersList.append(api.Orders.get(id="{}".format(x)))
        except:
            pass
    return ordersList


def pullProductsData(productsList):

    # loop over the list and get the products with the Ids
    # dont forget to update range (highest so far 2000)
    for x in range(0, 5):
        try:
            productsList.append(api.Products.get(id="{}".format(x)))
        except:
            pass
    return productsList

productOrdersListPulled, ordersListPulled, productsListPulled = createLists()
pullOrdersProductsData(productOrdersListPulled)
pullOrders(ordersListPulled)
pullProductsData(productsListPulled)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `productOrdersListPulled` from `api`;

```
from api import productOrdersListPulled
```

and your function `transformInDictionary` takes an argument with the same name.

```
def transformInDictionary(productOrdersListPulled):
```

You should rename the argument of your function.

```
def transformInDictionary(lst):
    for line in lst:
        productOrdersListWithLine = [ast.literal_eval(op) for op in re.findall(order_item, line)]
    return productOrdersListWithLine
```

And call it as follows: *(last line of your script)*

```
transformInDictionary(productOrdersListPulled)
```

Comment: How do I pass the `productOrdersListPulled `to `transformInDiciontary` if I use a different name?

Comment: Since you seem to want to use it as a global, you wouldn't as you don't need to.

Comment: that worked, thanks. now i have to fix the re module, that wont work with lists, only string  hehe

Answer (score 0):

First , i think your parameter name is too conflict .

Moreover , your method signature probably incorrect ? 
transformInDictionary take one argument , but you call with zero argument

I think this may solve your problem ?

```
from api import productOrdersListPulled as products #Give alias to productOrdersListPulled
def transformInDiction():
    """
    Change to zero argument
    """
    for line in products :
        product= [ast.literal_eval(op) for op in re.findall(order_item, line)]
    return product
transformInDiction()
```